# Replacing four 6V flooded lead acid (FLA) batteries with two 12V AGM in a floor scrubber. Will this work?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging

> How do I design a new battery system using two old but large AGM batteries in series?
>
> I realize a load test must be done to determine capacity differences.
> AGM batteries are also sensitive to overcharging, and voltage is temperature sensitive.
>
> What are the key critical design specs to define?
> I can follow this to implement a reliable design.

I have a floor scrubber that has four 6V flooded lead acid Trojan T-125 batteries. Problem is after using it to scrub the floor, it takes about 4 hours to recharge using the onboard 21A max charger.  Using a more powerful charger on them is not recommended as the batteries will heat up excessively and likely shorten their life.  I have a candidate solution though and wanted to know if it will work and what problems may arise.  At home I have 2 large (but identical) Odyssey PC2250 12V AGM batteries that are quite old (at least 10 years) but have a rated capacity of 126Ah.  They do not hold identical charges and one has slightly higher actual capacity than the other but they have not been in service for many years but I maintained them.  They usually hold 12.7V OCV (Open Circuit Voltage) which tells me they are still in decent condition.

So here is my plan and I would like to know if this will work or if I am headed down the wrong path.  I will do a load test on each of these batteries using my 12V power inverter and 500 watts of incandescent lights  as the actual load.  I will simply measure the duration of the test.  The inverter will beep when the load voltage drops to about 10.5V.  At that point I will shut off the inverter and put the battery back on the charger for a full charge.  I will do this same test for each battery solo and probably twice for each battery to confirm the results.  So assuming they are both similar Ah capacity (let's say the test lasts 1 hour each which would be about 42Ah each since 500W = about 42A at 12V), would it be ok to put these back into service but with a new task as floor scrubber batteries?  To get a quicker charge, I would use an external charger with 55A charge capability which will far exceed the onboard chargers maximum 21A rate.  I expect the actual charge time to go from about 4 hours on the old system to maybe 1.5 hours on the new system.

Comment: Open Circuit Voltage is not a good indication of the charge the battery has stored or battery health. Google battery universtiy

Comment: I must be missing something. The set of T-125 batteries has a nominal capacity of about 200 A-h. Although for some reason, you seem to be recharging them with only about 80 A-h. Are they old, too? What would be the point of replacing them with a set of old batteries (nominal capacity 126 A-h) that has maybe 75 A-h of capacity left?

Comment: Perhaps an alternate solution to this problem of being able to use the floor scrubber soon after putting it on the charger is to use more powerful batteries (Trojan T-145 for example), and use a more powerful external charger when it is known (or suspected)  it will be needed soon thereafter.  That way  I would have the option of using an external charger if I am in a rush or the slower charger if not in a rush.  However, I will still investigate the AGM candidate solution although I suspect because of the age of them, they wont last long under heavy load.

Comment: The main point is to be able to use the floor scrubber to within about 2 hours after it is put on the charger.  The AGM batteries will not last as long but can be used quicker after a charge is what I am thinking.  Also regarding the comment about OCV not being a good indicator of a battery's health: If after charging a 12V battery and letting it sit for many hours, an OCV reading of say 12.5V is taken, that IS an indicator there is some problem there, perhaps the battery has a high self discharge rate and/or it is "old and tired".

Comment: Why not have two sets of batteries, and use one while the other charges? Use an external charger as needed.

Comment: Can you use two 12 V chargers, one for each battery? That will help balancing the batteries and you can push more power into it in two hours.

Comment: @Passerby -  It would be too much work for the people that use the floor scrubber to swap out the drained batteries and swap in the fully charged ones. The main advantage of AGM technology is they can be fully charged within 1 hour (2 hours is better). I actually tested this one time.  I drained a 12V 14Ah AGM battery down to 10.5V under a reasonable load which is considered nearly full drained. I put it on a 25A charger for 1 hour and although it was warm to the touch afterwards, it run the complete charge curve to 100% SoC.  I was impressed. 2 hours at 40A for the big batteries might work.

Comment: @winny - I considered this idea such as using a pair of 12V 25A chargers but a problem there is extra complexity for whoever uses the floor scrubber.  They would have to be keen enough to connect to the proper terminals to get that to work.  I do use this technique on a 36V golf cart because it seems to charge better than the 36V charger but I have experience and know what I am doing (somewhat).   I still think the pair of large AGM batteries with a 24V 40A charger is a good candidate solution.  This is for indoor use so AGM is a better choice cuz FLA releases fumes and has higher maintenance.

Comment: Good. You seem to know what you are doing and the associated trade offs. Having worked with battery chargers for the majority of my career, I highly recommend fully float charging each battery individually every one in a while to equalize them.

Comment: @winny - As a side note (but related to this question), I use different charge techniques on the 36V golf cart to hopefully have it maintain good health. For example, if I am not in a hurry to use it, I will slow charge it overnight for something like 12 hours and as low as 2A (0.01C). Those are about 200Ah batteries in there. If I am in a rush then I just use the regular 36V 21A charger. My large AGM batteries are over 10 years old (possibly 15 years old) but they still seem to hold an estimated 75Ah (out of their 126Ah rated) of capacity. I charge them occasionally to counter self discharge.

Comment: My man! That's how you do it. That, and maintaining your fluid levels, which is the only downside of AGM - you can't replace lost water.

Comment: I'm still failing to see any actual engineering question here. It seems to be more about the care and feeding of two particular sets of rather old batteries. Is there any hope of bringing this on-topic?

Comment: @DaveTweed - I have seen other similar questions on this site but not addressing my exact concern and those were not marked as off-topic.  Part of Engineering is making good compromises and this is an application of that.  One question I ask myself is why didn't the floor scrubber manufacturer use AGM batteries in the first place and a more powerful charger?  Ideally a charger that could be set to either fast or slow charge mode depending on the need.  Cost maybe?

Comment: This requires 2 batteries within 2% matching otherwise, balancers are required for charging and UV protection for cutout.

Comment: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/uc2906.pdf

Comment: @winny - Your recommendation of using 2 chargers actually turned out the be part of my solution.  I can get a pair of 120V input, 12V 55A output chargers and put one on each battery.  I doubt I could use them on the same 15A circuit so the only drawback there is I have to use 2 different outlets.  My guess is that they will each draw 1000+ watts and here in USA, each standard 15A outlet maxes out at 1875 watts.  Where the floor scrubber normally "lives", there may be some 20A outlets in which case 2 chargers on the same outlet may work without tripping the circuit breaker.  I will investigate.

Comment: Can you get two efficient ones with PFC? 2*13.6*55 = 1496 W, leaving headroom for as low as 80 % efficiency. Hmm, far from all on the market will do that, but you can always find one with a bit lower current. 80 % efficiently is a resonable assumption but a PF of 1 isn't true for all chargers.

Comment: @winny - Usually the PF (Power Factor) improves when the charger is at or near full rated output power and PF gets worse when it is at a small fraction of its rated power.  I have to retest the first large AGM battery so I can see if I get consistent results or by cycling it , if it is improving or getting worse.  Also I am considering using these 2 large AGM batteries in a golf cart which would allow me to charge it very quickly like play 18 holes, and fully charge it in 1 hour at 55A starting current while I eat lunch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will work.  My best candidate solution so far is to first load test the pair of Odyssey PC2250 12V 126Ah rated AGM batteries solo and record the actual Ah rating of each.  If they are both at least 75Ah for example, they still may be usable.  To charge them, I would use 2 separate 12V 55A chargers that work on standard 120VAC (60Hz) here in USA.  I would assume the 2 batteries could remain connected in series (24VDC) even while they are being charged separately by separate chargers.  At 55A max, assuming the batteries only hold a true 75Ah max, the maximum charge time should be no more than 2 hours, likely less (perhaps 1.5 hours).  I do not know the actual load of the floor scrubber but if I did, it would likely be best to simulate that load.  However, using my 500 watt load might suffice to determine the relative performance of the 2 batteries.  For example, if one battery lasts 1.5 hours at 500 watts and the other only 1 hour, I might then have a problem.

Results of the load test were as follows:

800 watt max rated non pure sine wave output 12V power inverter was used.  This is low quality output with much distortion but adequate for load testing.

Load was a pair of 300 watt incandescent bulbs estimated to draw 250 watts at the lower voltage (estimated 110V) output of the inverter.

Battery # 1 (the expected weaker one from previous other load testing)

Part 1: 48 minutes at an estimated 500 watts.

Part 2: Load was then reduced to approximately 250 watts for another 0.5 hours (one bulb was turned off with no interruption of load).

Total calculated watt hours is therefore (0.8 hours * 0.5 kW) + (0.5 * 0.25 kW) = 0.4 KWh + 0.125 Kwh = 0.525 KWh  There was supposed to be a part 3 with an even lower load but I cancelled it cuz the load is not representative of a floor scrubber so it is not really relevant but I would call the battery about 0.6KWh total had I let part 3 conclude.  Remember the KWh rating of a battery decreases when the average load increases.  If the floor scrubber is something like 50A at 24VDC, this first battery wont do well cuz it only lasted 0.8 hours at an estimated 42A.

Part 1 of the test is the most significant since the load of the floor scrubber will likely be constant.  Part 2 is just to better inform me how much total capacity the battery has but is not really relevant to high loads.

The battery is now slow charging overnight at 2A setting unattended but when I get my new charger I will blast it with 55A for about 1 hour or however long it takes to get a 100% charge.  Since the battery is so old, I am not sure if it will "like" 55A of charge current and I may have to use the slower 20A charge mode.  Perhaps doing many charge/discharge cycles will improve the Ah capacity of it since it has been sitting so long out of service.

I will slightly "overcharge" it and try this test again to see if I can get close to 1 hour at the 500 watt load.  Even if I get that, it is  only about half as long as a healthy battery should last so something is wrong with my battery, likely it is way past it's usable service life and should be "retired" to a much easier life such as UPS backup duty which is rarely needed here.

Comment: The weakest of any cell determines the Ah capacity. the cells are sealed which makes it more difficult. to know you are overcharging any 1 cell. THis can lead to accelerated aging.  I suggest you overcharge them 5% to attempt to equalize the cells and check the ESR but the step load Vrise during static load test. ESR will rise as SoC drops depending on % of cell mismatch.  For charging to prevent unbalance use an OVP active Zener FET transistor to bypass battery charge current thru a dummy 1V/55A wire with a lower RdsOn than the wire heater. 55W bypass is equiv to 10% mismatch batteries.

Comment: plot Vbat VS time and no load and measure Vbat no load for a few seconds then resume load . From this compute in a spreadsheet V and Delta V vs T,,which is a strong indicator of approaching 10% SoC and dead battery from rise is delta V as well as Vmin at 11.5V

Comment: @TonyStewart - can you give me more details on how to do your test?  I did the load test and didn't get encouraging results.  The true Ah capacity of the first battery (and expected weaker of the 2 batteries) at high load (close to 50A load) seems to be slightly less than 1 hour.

Comment: Like I said measure V and Delta V and preferably I during discharge test where Delta V/I= ESR  and charge capacity =I*t... try burning off some sulphation with 5~8% over voltage after full charge with a large series R overnight and see if capacity improves.

Comment: I only got 0.8 hours at about 42A load which is about 33.6 Ah before my power inverter started to beep to warn me of low input voltage.  The attached chart indicates a healthy PC-2250 battery should yield about 2 hours of output with an approximate 500W load on it.  I got less than half of this but maybe running the test twice will yield better results the 2nd time.  I will try it and I will try to measure the actual load use a Kill-A-Watt meter but I don't think that will be accurate with non pure sine wave AC output from the inverter.http://www.odysseybatteries.com/batteries/pc2250.htm

Comment: @TonyStewart - can I do your overcharge / sulfation burn idea using my 3A (max) laboratory power supply (lab PSU)?  I can set that anywhere from 0.0 to 30.0 V and 3A max.  It has both Constant Current (CC) and Constant Voltage (CV) modes.  Normally, AGM chargers prevent charge voltages of more than 2.45V per cell (so no more than 14.7V for a 12V 6 cell battery).  I can set my lab PSU to go above that but limit the current to whatever I want (such as 1.5A).  What settings would you recommend?  Allow it to go up to the full 3A max output with maybe a 15.0V limit?  What duration should I hold it?

Comment: limit current to 0.5A @15.3V for 1 day. check for H2 degassing tube vent for evaporating electrolyte . If little or none raise current, to 1A otherwise adjust accordingly for small flow agitating plates.

Comment: @TonyStewart - if it ever gets to that high of a voltage.  I cannot fix and force the voltage to be that high and hold the current low.  More likely the CC (Constant Current) mode (more accurately max current) mode will force the charge voltage to be MUCH lower than 15.3V to only flow 0.5A.  The battery is very old though so its behavior will not be like that of a new battery.  I will try and see what happens.  I assume I should do this to each battery solo and not wired in series like give the 24V bank 30V max at 0.5A max for 24 hours or should I do it to both solo then again series combined?

Comment: another approach is very low duty cycle 10A pulses at whatever voltage

Comment: I would not run it for that long as a full day. For a flooded battery you can replace the lost water but for AGM your outgassing is forever lost.

Comment: @winny - r u sure about that?  I thought there was a way to add water to even AGM batteries.  I have a battery shop closeby perhaps they can check.  Also, one of my large AGM batteries is only showing about 50% of its rated capacity so is there anything I can do to help increase that?  How about if I just  allow it to draw up to 0.5A from my lab PSU but set the max voltage at 14.7 which is the industry standard max V for a 12V AGM battery?  I could leave it like that for maybe 12 to 16 hours.  I have that battery fully charged now so I will put it on the lab PSU set for 0.5A max and observe.

Comment: There might be exceptions but all AGMs I've seen have been sealed. If you can open it and refill the water, go for 16-17 V until it's bubbling and refill any lost water.

Comment: I will ask the local battery shop if there is anything I can do to an old AGM battery to help increase its capacity.  I put it on the lab PSU set at 14.7V max and surprisingly is drew about 1.5 amps in CC mode as it didn't quite reach 14.7V even after about 12 hours so I am not quite sure what conclusions I can draw from that and that was AFTER I had already given it a full charge with a smart charger.  I will repeat the drain test soon to see if I can beat 48 minutes at about a 500 W load.  I am trying to get 1 hour minimum and even that is only about 50% of its advertised capacity.